# Angular 2 e2e respect test execution order?

Tags: angular, protractor, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

How to make Angular 2 e2e tests executes in the same order as declared ?

*I use Angular-cli.*

Comment: From what I recall, the default execution order in Protractor+Jasmine is exactly the way tests are declared..could you elaborate or/and add a specific example?

Answer (score 2):

When you write some test cases in order like this.

Test 1
Test 3 
Test 2 
Test 4

This will execute in 1, 3, 2 and 4 in linear fashion. or we can say FIFO.
Until unless the following test case doesn't have any dependency over the earlier one. for eg. Test 3 dependent on Test 2.

So always whatever the order we write it will execute in that order.